# Permission errors with the `find` command

Tags: shell, command-line

When using the `find` command from `~` or `/`, it is common to get errors related to access rights (`Permission denied` or `Operation not permitted`).

Running the `find` command with `sudo` removes some of these errors, but not all, and anyway running the command with elevated privileges is not an option.

So the question is: does the `find` command have a flag similar to the `grep` silent mode flag (`grep -s`) that would prevent these errors?

---

Edit:

The solution of removing all errors suggested several times on this page is not very elegant and potentially dangerous (`find / 2>/dev/null`).

A good solution comes from this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42842/199660. For example:
`find / -type f -iname "*balance*.pdf" 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted' | grep -v 'Permission denied' | grep -v 'No such file or directory' | grep -v 'Not a directory'`

Still, it would be nice that `find` provides a flag for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not in favor of the proposed duplicate, as it suppresses _every_ error, not just the permission-related ones. That makes the result unreliable. `find` has an option `-readable`; haven't tried it myself but it sounds promising.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "bash `find` command". `find` is not part of bash, is available without bash installed, and works the same way no matter which shell you're using or even if it's invoked without any shell at all (f/e, `subprocess.Popen(['find', '/'])` in Python).

Comment: `-readable` by itself won't help, but `! -readable -prune` appears to help. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42841/how-to-skip-permission-denied-errors-when-running-find-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect them to /dev/ null using.
`find / 2>/dev/null`